# Unable to use latex for matplotlib ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, latex

I am trying to set the ticks on the axis of a matplotlib plot using latex. While the latex for the title and the labels for the x and y axis are rendering correctly, the text for the ticks do not render correctly.

The following is an example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = "stix"
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'STIXGeneral'

x = np.arange(1,4)
y = x*x

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xlabel(r"$\mathfrak{X}$")
plt.ylabel(r"$\mathfrak{Y}$")
plt.title(r"$\mathfrak{T}$")
frame = plt.gca()
frame.set_xticklabels(r'$\mathfrak{t}_i$')
plt.show()
```

Running this code, I get the following result:
[image: Result1]

As you can see the x ticks are not rendered correctly.

I have also enabled `text.usetex` on rcParams. But that causes another problem. Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = "stix"
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'STIXGeneral'
plt.rc('text', usetex=1)
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'].append(r'\usepackage{amsfonts}')

x = np.arange(1,4)
y = x*x

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xlabel(r"$\mathfrak{X}$")
plt.ylabel(r"$\mathfrak{Y}$")
plt.title(r"$\mathfrak{T}$")
frame = plt.gca()
frame.set_xticklabels(r"$\mathfrak{Q}$")
plt.show()
```

Running this code, I will get an error saying `LaTeX was not able to process the following string: '$'`. There will be no problem if I don't use latex for the ticks.

Should I set some other parameters to use latex for the ticks? Also, it is  important for me to use "stix" font for the ticks.

I appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: what do you expect the tick labels to be? seems like you are trying to set them to either `t` or `Q`, but you haven't defined them anywhere

Comment: `set_xticklabels` expects a list of labels to use for each tick. As you are just giving it a string, it is using each character in order for successive ticks.

Comment: You probably want to use the http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter with a string like `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mticks.FormatStrFormatter(r'$\mathfrac{%d}$'))`

Comment: @tom This is just an example. I just want to use latex (with stix format) to set the ticks of the plot, whether it is `t` or `Q`.

Comment: @tcaswell I did the following: `frame.set_xticklabels(r"xyz");
frame.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.FormatStrFormatter(r'$\mathfrac{%s}$'))`. This does not work either. That formatter is processing the cooridnates and not the `xticklabels`.